# Emulate a full-featured switch in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I have read [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python?lq=1) and none of the answers seem to fully emulate a switch.

I know you can use `if elif else` or a dictionary but I'm wondering... is it possible in Python to fully emulate a switch including fall-through and default (without defining an enormous function before-hand)?

I am not overly concerned with performance and am mainly interested in readability and want to get the logical layout of a switch statement as in C-like languages in Python

Is this achievable or not?

Comment: May I ask _why_ you're trying to do this? Generally there are better ways of tackling things in Python which is why the switch statement isn't part of the language...

Comment: @JonCage I am asking purley out of curiosity but for the sake of argument; imagine that you had c code that you wanted to convert to python (for whatever reason) and it contained a ````switch```` satement which used fallthrough and default.

Comment: The documentation suggests that an `if ... elif ... else` block is the analog to a `switch / case` statement from other languages: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements.  Is there any particular reason you're not happy with that construction?

Comment: @g.d.d.c you don't get fall-through

Comment: What can we possibly add here, given that you've read everything from the previous question? PEP 3103 is pretty clear.

Comment: I'd be suprised if you could show us a concrete example of some C code which uses fall-through which couldn't be written better in some other way in Python without emulating a switch statement..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't seem to be answerable. OP links several resources stating there is nothing EXACTLY like he's trying to do, then asks how to EXACTLY do it.

Comment: @AdamSmith Read my question carefully. I link one post that gives answers that come close; I don't think any of them say that what I'm asking can't be done (correct me if I'm wrong :) ) but I'm asking 'is it possible' **not** 'how do I'. 'No it isn't possible' is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @JonCage You might be right. There well probably always be a better way from a performance stand-point but often when I'm making python scripts, performance is not my main concern. I don't care if it takes a couple of milliseconds longer to run as much as I care about readability; especially so if I or a co-worker may need to modify the script months or even years later.

Comment: @nettux443 if readability is your main concern then you should try to generate idiomatic Python, not Python that tries to be C. Someday you'll get a coworker that's never used a C-like language and they'll be going "WTF?" P.S. do you know how many bugs have been caused by lack of a `break` in switch statements? That's not something I'd want to emulate.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't disagree with anything you've said but I'd still like to know if it could be done.

Comment: @nettux443 the consensus appears to be no, but I think closing the question to possible answers was a little drastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As you don't want to use a dictionary or if elif else*, the closest possible emulation, AFAIK, would be something like this:

```
class switch(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.fall = False

    def __iter__(self):
        """Return the match method once, then stop"""
        yield self.match
        raise StopIteration

    def match(self, *args):
        """Indicate whether or not to enter a case suite"""
        if self.fall or not args:
            return True
        elif self.value in args: # changed for v1.5, see below
            self.fall = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

import string
c = 'A'
for case in switch(c):
    if case(*string.lowercase): # note the * for unpacking as arguments
        print "c is lowercase!"
        break
    if case(*string.uppercase):
        print "c is uppercase!"
        break
    if case('!', '?', '.'): # normal argument passing style also applies
        print "c is a sentence terminator!"
        break
    if case(): # default
        print "I dunno what c was!"
```

@Author Brian Beck

@source: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410692/ <- there are other suggestions there, you might want to check to see if **any is good enough for you**.

***Note that you will have to use (or import this class switch)***

Comment: I'm torn between +1 for ingenuity and -1 for horror.

Comment: This has also [been posted on the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6606540).

Comment: Does this solution allow fall-through as in ````case('.'): 'do something' case('!','?'): 'do something else' break````?